# How should endorsements be used?

Tags: blog

I have a long and analytic article. By its nature, it's hard to get clicks, and even raise skepticism. Luckily, I have an endorsement from a person who is regarded as expert in the field, and I am permitted to use that endorsement.

How should I present that endorsement effectively? Should I put it at the top to catch more eyes, or at the bottom to leave the introduction first? How should I present it so that people won't perceive it as bragging?

I'm gonna put it in the red rectangle.
[image]

Comment: If it's hard to get clicks, potential readers won't even reach the endorsement. If this is for a blog, maybe include the endorsement in the preview snippet (or however else you link to the article).

Comment: I add an image to illustrate this. Can you check?